# Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, dbi

Whenever I'm executing the program below, I get the error message `Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value` from following line:

```
$sth->execute($agent_name,$service_id,$call_start_time,$call_end_time);
```

but in same program I'm able to execute the first SQL query indicated in the comments below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI;

my $DSN = q/dbi:ODBC:SQLSERVER/;
my $uid = q/ivr/;
my $pwd = q/ivr/;
my $DRIVER = "Freetds";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd) or die "Coudn't Connect SQL";
my $servernumber = 2;

my $service_name = "JM";
my $agent_name= 'Balaji';
my $call_start_time='2013-07-01 15:46:50.865';
my $call_end_time='2013-07-15 15:46:50.789';
my $call_rec_file_name;

my $rows_fund = $dbh->selectrow_array("select count(service_name) from cti_services  where service_name='$service_name'");
my $rows_agent = $dbh->selectrow_array("select count(agent_name) from cti_agents where agent_name='$agent_name'");

# This query successfully executes:
my $sql_fund = "select service_id from cti_services where service_name='$service_name'";
my $sth_fund = $dbh->prepare($sql_fund);
$sth_fund->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
my $service_id = $sth_fund->fetchrow();
print $service_id,"\n";

if( $rows_fund == 1 && $rows_agent == 1 )
{
    my $sql="select top(10) service_name,agent_name,call_rec_file_name,call_start_time,call_end_time from cti_agents join  cti_call_master on (agent_name = call_agent_name) join cti_services on (call_service_id = service_id) where agent_name = ? and call_rec_file_name is not null and service_id=? and call_start_time between ? and ?";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    # The problem is with this query. I'm getting the error "Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value".
    $sth->execute($agent_name,$service_id,$call_start_time,$call_end_time);

    print "Service Name","Agent Name","Call Start Time ","Call End Time","Sound File " ;
    while (my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array())
    {
        my ($service_name,$agent_name,$call_rec_file_name,$call_start_time,$call_end_time ) = @data;
        print "$service_name","$agent_name ","$call_start_time ","$call_end_time ","  $call_rec_file_name ";
    }
}
else
{
    print "<em>","There is no data found","</em>";
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

What could be causing the error message?

Answer (score 3):

`$sth` is undefined because your call to `$dbh->prepare` is failing for some reason.

If you replace your DBI->connect() call with the following, you'll get the error from the `prepare` call rather than it failing silently and bombing out when you try to call `execute`:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd, { RaiseError => 1 });
```

You can read more about RaiseError and the other attributes available to DBI calls here: https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#RaiseError

I must admit I can't immediately see the error, my hunch is an SQL syntax issue, but I don't speak SQLServer.

Comment: same problem when i use this syntax  "my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd, { RaiseError => 1 });"   error is that Can't call method “execute” on an undefined value.Error come from variable declaration(value undefined) which I already declare.

Comment: Right, but you should get an additional error telling you why the prepare failed.

Comment: Can't call method "fetchrow_array" on an undefined value at /var/www/html/perl-ajax.pl line 32.

Comment: Is that definitely the only error you're getting, rather than just the _last_ error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Change the first two lines inside the `if` to this

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<__SQL__) or die $dbh->errstr;
SELECT TOP(10) service_name, agent_name, call_rec_file_name, call_start_time, call_end_time
FROM cti_agents
JOIN cti_call_master ON (agent_name = call_agent_name)
JOIN cti_services ON (call_service_id = service_id)
WHERE agent_name = ?
AND call_rec_file_name IS NOT NULL
AND service_id = ?
AND call_start_time BETWEEN ? AND ?
__SQL__
```

then you will see the reason for the error.

Note that there *must be no spaces* before or after `__SQL__`.

Comment: Enlighten us ... are you saying OP will see it because formatting the SQL better will make it clearer where the issue is? I'm curious :-)

Comment: @JamesGreen: I'm saying that checking the result of `prepare` directly and dying with the error string if it fails will make the problem the *last* thing it reports and prevent it from ever trying to use an undefined statement handle.

Comment: Why not just add the `or die ...` to the existing code (`my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)`)? Changing it to a heredoc seems like a potentially confusing change for a beginner.

Comment: @DaveCross: I took the view that the existing code is confusing for *everybody*, and any bugs in the SQL would be all but impossible to spot in a line of code well over 300 characters long. There is little point in helping someone to generate a `prepare failed: syntax error` message if the SQL is impregnable. You are free to offer your own answer of course.

Comment: @Borodin after follow your given code I got following errors 1) "Use of uninitialized value in die at /var/www/html/xyz.pl line 30"   2) " Died at /var/www/html/xyz.pl line 30". I declare all the variable properly mention.I don't know why this is die.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes inside the sql for the datetimes, it may be seeing the white space during parsing?